# How we can aggregate prediction from a forecast?

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, aggregation

Let's say that I have a time series forecast of form:

May 104.4
June 103.5
July 107.4
September 109.2

Afterwards I would like to compute an aggregated forecast for the period. Can I just compute simple mean of the forecast's means and prediction intervals? Is that a valid solution?

Comment: No. See https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecast-intervals-for-aggregates/

Comment: Thank you Rob. I faced a little issue: when I use the mentioned simulation for ARIMA model both the mean and PI values are substantially higher than these from a regular prognosis. Do you know why?

Comment: Please post reproducible code and I'll have a look.

Comment: My bad - I forgot to add xreg variables to my simulation. Thank you for help!

Comment: Rob I have one more question. Let's say I have a prediction of 12 weeks ahead. I'd like to aggregate them to consecutive months. How can I obtain PI for each aggregated month?